# How to display root subnodes in MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

Is there any ways I can display root subnodes in MvcSiteMapProvider
So i can have my menu looking like that:

**|Home| |About| |Etc|**

**|Item1|**

**|Item2|**

I want **Item1** and **Item2** would appeared  like index(home) subelements.

Here is my sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1" controller="Item1" action="Index"/> /**should desplayed like submenu element of Home
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item2" controller="Item2" action="Index"/> /**should desplayed like submenu element of Home

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="About" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Etc" controller="Etc" action="Index"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode />
```

But in my case i have

**|Home| |Item1| |Item2| |About| |Etc|** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at this one: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/160
see how sitemap declared there. In your case you go like that:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Root" clickable="false" changeFrequency="Always">

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item1" controller="Item1" action="Index"/>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Item2" controller="Item2" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode/>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="About" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Etc" controller="Etc" action="Index"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode />
```

also you need to build your menu like that:

```
 @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false)
```

Because by default "show starting node" is set to `true`.